# android sdk version not found in react-native-community/cli doctor

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

I ran npx @react-native-community/cli doctor, and I encountered the following error:

[capture of doctor log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ1Hq.png)

I'm seeing an error related to the Android SDK, where it is looking for a version called .b33.0.0, but I couldn't find any information about this version. It doesn't seem to follow the standard Android SDK versioning format.

What does the .b33.0.0 version represent in the context of the Android SDK? Is this a valid version, or is it possibly a bug or error from the React Native CLI?

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Checked and installed the latest Android SDK.
Verified that the ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set correctly.
Tried various solutions found online, but none of them resolved the issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't resolve this error, however somehow I was able to still run my app via the command `npx react-native@latest run-android`. I'd still be interested in how to resolve this problem after all though.